# Multimeter temperature coefficient - Specified accuracy

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement, accuracy, resolution

I want to calculate the temperature coefficient for a digital multimeter.
The datasheet I read it is calculated as:

0.1*(specified accuracy)/°C (<18°C or >28°C)

Do you know what specified accuracy stands for?

I mean, can I consider specified accuracy as the composition of multimeter accuracy and resolution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't think that it "stands for" anything.  It's the accuracy, as specified in the meter's handbook.

Comment: I think that the accuracy is specified by calibration report of the instrument.

Answer (score 1):

According to Full scale Accuracy:

Accuracy of a multimeter is given as a function of specified accuracy .

Accuracy = (specified accuracy / 100 ) * FSD.

FSD refers to full scale deflection which is the largest value can the multimeter measures.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you quote the source of this explanation please?

Comment: Electronic Instrumentation and Measurements, 2nd Edition
David Bell .

Comment: Specified accuracy related to analog multimeter